# Move color of an HTML element to another page

Tags: javascript

Good evening,
i was working on a part of what i hope will be my future website and i wanted to add a "photograpy" section to it, and here comes the problem.
since the title in the main page constatly changes color, i'd like to grab its current color to transfer it to the title of the other page to play an animation later on.
the problem is that when i press the related button, i am taken to the photograpy page, but the title remains black.
i've tried seraching for help on google but i haven't been able to find much.
here is the JS

```
if (document.addEventListener) {
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
        loaded();
    });
} else if (document.attachEvent) {
    document.attachEvent("onreadystatechange", function() {
        loaded();
    });
}

function loaded() {
    document.getElementById("PHtitle").style.color === titlecolor;
}

function script() {
    const titlecolor = document.getElementById("title").style.color;
};

document.getElementById('photograpy').onclick = function () {
    script();
};
```

Comment: "else if (document.attachEvent)" — Please find a tutorial written this century. There's no reason to be supporting Internet Explorer 8 in 2022.

Comment: If the user is being directed to another page then you'd need to include or persist information about this somehow.  It could be a query string parameter on the URL of that other page (not ideal UX, but can work), it could be in a cookie or local storage, etc.  But basically *anything* you do in-memory on Page A is lost once the user navigates to Page B.

Answer (score 1):

The snippets don't allow for localStorage, so here is just the javascript.

First, I let the variables outside of a function. The titleColor function checks to see if titleColor was saved in localStorage, if not the default color is black.

Then I set the color of the phtitle to the contents of titleColor variable.

In the script function, I set the localStorage variable to the getComputedStyle color of the title.

Then last I use an event listener on the button to run the script for saving the color.

LocalStorage is a way to store data in the user's browser until they close their browser/clear their data etc.. Which will allow it to be usable on different pages then where it was saved.

```
    let titleColor = localStorage.getItem("titleColor") || "#000000";
    let PHtitle = document.querySelector("#PHtitle");
    let title = document.querySelector("#title");
    let btn = document.querySelector("#photography");
    
if(PHtitle){
    PHtitle.style.color = titleColor;
}
    
    function script() {
      localStorage.setItem("titleColor", getComputedStyle(title).color)
    }
    
if(btn && title){
    btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
      script();
    })
}
```

Comment: i tried this but in the browser console it's giving me an error
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'style') at photography.js:6:9"

Comment: @u0lf, that means that object doesn't exist that is being referred to. Make sure whatever is being referred to at that line exists on the page. Also, the javascript should be loaded at the BOTTOM of the body and NOT in the head/top of the page.

Comment: alright so from what i've been able to understand it's not able to read the PHtitle that's in the photography page from the main page and in the photography page it's not reading the button from the main page

Comment: @u0lf I updated my answer to include if statements. But you should probably update the code so that it works for you specific needs since every page doesn't have the same objects.